# Want to run Nomad agent as a service

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2012-r2, nomad

I want to run nomad agent service in windows server 2012 R2.

I used `sc.exe` command which looked like this:

```
sc.exe create nomadservice binpath="nomad.exe agent -config=C:/nomad/client.hcl"
```

This created a service though it isn't started. I tried increasing the timeout to 60 seconds still the service gets stuck at starting and does not acquire running mode.

Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have succesfully run nomad as windows service via http://nssm.cc/

Looks like developers haven't realised this feature out of the box for windows platform.